# how can I assign the same random number to 2 variables in swift?

Tags: swift

I am building an app that the user selects a multiplication table. Then it gives random numbers to multiplicate with the number they select. for example, if the user selects "1". the questions shown would be "1 x 1", or "1 x 8".
The problem is that I need to assign the same random number to 2 variables. The one that will be shown on the question and the one used to calculate the result.
I thought of something like this, but the random number is different on each variable. What can I do to use the same random number generated on 2 variables?

```
    func game() -> (String, Int) {
    let randomNumber = multiplicate.randomElement()
    
    switch selectedQuestion {
    case 0:
        return ("1 × \(randomNumber!)", 1 * randomNumber!)
    
    default:
        return ("", 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking but you could do something like this:

```
let number = Int.random(in: 0..<10)

let number2 = number
```

but I don't think there is a need to create a new variable for this. The whole idea of variables is that you can save some value and then use it later so there isn't really a need to create `number2` here.

Comment: it doesnt work. the 2 variables are different. I get (1x6) and 9 (I wanted the result (1x6) and 6 as the answer.)